# Unable to enable AVB under Mavericks on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, macos

I have a MacBook Pro that has the Thunderbolt hardware which means it should be able to support EthernetAVB. I have done a search and found the command to enable it at the website [Manual Pagez](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/avbdeviced/). The command it outlines is avbdeviced and then I place --list-interfaces after it to have it list the devices that can work with EthernetAVB.

When I run the command in terminal (either as sudo or just plain) even after going up to root I receive a response like this

```
BradfordBenns-MacBook-Pro:/ bradfordbenn$ avbdeviced --list-interface
-bash: avbdeviced: command not found
BradfordBenns-MacBook-Pro:/ bradfordbenn$ sudo avbdeviced --list-interface
Password:
sudo: avbdeviced: command not found
```

I believe that the system has everything installed as I have a directory called Macintosh HD:Library:Audio:Plug-Ins:HAL:AppleAVBAudio.driver:Contents:MacOS:AppleAVBAudio

Is there a step I am missing or how do I enable the AVB feature?

The more formal information about the system:

> System Version:   OS X 10.9 (13A603)
>   Kernel Version:   Darwin 13.0.0
>   Boot Volume:  Macintosh HD   Boot
>   Mode: Normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVB no longer needs to be enabled under OS X 10.9. avbdeviced has been removed.

You should be able to view and connect devices via 'Window' -> 'Network Device Browser' in Audio MIDI Setup.

Comment: Thanks I will verify that once I get back to the system.